# NestJS authentication strategy - how is it accessed?

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

So, I am confused. I'm slowly getting a grip around NestJS but the way `passport` works has me baffled.

I followed the [tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication) and everything works.

I created a JWT Strategy:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {
        super({
            jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
            secretOrKey: 'topSecret51',
        });
    }

    async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<User | null> {
        const { email } = payload;
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findOne({
            where: { email }
        });

        if (!user) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Athorisation not provided')
        }
        return user;
    }
}
```

And defined the module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule.register({
      defaultStrategy: 'jwt',
    }),
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'topSecret51',
      signOptions: {
        expiresIn: 3600,
      },
    })
  ],
  providers: [UserService, PrismaService, JwtStrategy],
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

And **voila** a valid token is issued. What I don't understand is how `passport` accesses the `JwtStrategy`. How is passport aware that there is a file in my folder structure that contains a `JwtStrategy`?

1.) It is not dependency injected by the `PassportModule` or `JWTModule`
2.) It is not passed as an argument to any method

Is there some behind-the-scenes magic that looks through all providers and determines if any of them is a sub-class of the argument provided to `PassportStrategy`?

Answer (score 7):

There's a lot of magic that goes on with the passport module for NestJS. I will do what I can to explain how it all works, though sometimes it goes even beyond me.

The first thing to note is that each `PassportStrategy` **has to** extend the abstract mixin `PassportStrategy`. This mixin takes in a `Strategy` from the regular passport package (`passport-jwt` in this case). This strategy has a default name with it (`jwt` here), but you can pass a second argument to supply your own name.

Nest does some really cool magic to pass the values from `CustomStrategy`'s constructor's `super()` call to passports normal registration. It then takes `CustomStrategy#validate` and applies it to passport's verify callback, which is the reason that the `validate` method **must** match passport's expected `verify` callback.

Now we've done some registration with passport, but for these to be called properly, we need to look into the `AuthGuard` mixin. Normally,  we can pass a strategy to the mixin, and this strategy needs to match a passport strategy's name (like `jwt` in this case) or it can be set in the `PassportModule`'s `defaultStrategy` option. From here, the guard does a little bit of magic to call the strategy by name (`jwt`, `google`, `local`, etc) and pass the `request`, the `response`, and `next` from the http context Nest creates. At the end of the call, `request.user` gets set by the returned value from `passports.authenticate`.